# k-means clustering with pamk CBI problems

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have been trying to cluster my data to be able to sort out the different intensities. From the graph bellow you can see two distinct groups. Other plots like this are not so easilly distinquished so I thought k-means with a cluster estimation would be a good way to go. So I am using from the `fpc` package the function pamkCBI (basically the same as pamk just with an output I find is easier to use) and I am trying to get my data (also bellow) clustered. The problem I have is that the data are being clustered along the x-axis which produces two clusters with the top peak in one and the low peaks in the other set. I need it to distinguish between the V1-V8 lines. I was thinking just cluster along the y-axis by translocating columns and rows, but then I get this error:

```
Error in summary(silhouette(clustering[ss[[i]]], dx))$avg.width : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

There has to be a way this can be done. If anyone has any suggestions, or another way to do this, using a different package (even a different program or a different clustering technique) I'd appreciate it. Sorry for the long question.

```
library(flexmix)
library(fpc)
cluster <- pamkCBI(mt,krange=1:100,criterion="multiasw", usepam=FALSE,
     scaling=FALSE, diss=FALSE,
     critout=FALSE, ns=10, seed=NULL)
```

[Example test matrix](http://sdrv.ms/WrLHjS)

[image: What the data looks like]